# How to check one window or dialog is displayed or not by pywinauto

Tags: python, modal-dialog, pywinauto

I am new in `pywinauto` and have just started learning. Now I am using `pywinauto` to do some auto tests. So I need to know how to check one dialog is displayed or not.

For example:

```py
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application()
app.connect(process=1234)
main_window = app.window(class_name='YodaoMainWndClass')
```

At here, I want to check the main_window is visible or not. But I don't know how to do this. maybe I should call `__getattribute__` or other functions?

Answer (score 1):

Method `.exists()` returns `True` or `False` (if it doesn't exist for 5 seconds by default). It could look like this:

```
main_window = app.window(class_name='YodaoMainWndClass', visible_only=True)
if main_window.exists(timeout=10):
    pass # do something
```

If the window is not appeared and we should fail the test, it's easier to make sure we couldn't wait till it's open. Method `.wait()` is more preferable then:

```
main_window = app.window(class_name='YodaoMainWndClass')
main_window.wait('visible', timeout=10)
```

Method `.wait()` will raise an exception `ElementNotFoundError` is case the timeout is over, otherwise execution will continue.

See chapter [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html) for more details.

Comment: I can't seem to catch a pywinauto.ElementNotFoundError. Neither does catching a pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError seem to work. I want to test that a dialog does NOT appear. The only workaround I found is to catch all exceptions. Wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: @AdamE can you create an issue on GitHub with more details? Some code example would be helpful.